# Regarding function template argument deduction

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Here is the example from 14.8.2.1, paragraph 3:

```
template <class T> int f(T&& heisenreference);
template <class T> int g(const T&&);
int i;
int n1 = f(i); // #1
int n2 = f(0);
int n3 = g(i);
```

In the case of #1, the **final** function template parameter type would be `T` because the same paragraph suggests

> ... If P is a
>   reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction...

At the same time, the **final** argument would be `lvalue reference to int` because, again, the same paragraph suggests

> ... If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue,
>   the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

In conclusion, `T` is identical to `lvalue reference to int`. However, once `lvalue reference to int` fit into the place of `T`, the type no longer makes sense because `T&& heisenreference` will be `rvalue reference to lvalue reference to int heisenreference`. In fact, I already know the right answer is `lvalue reference to int`, but I don't know how to get to that conclusion strictly by the standard.

Comment: `T` is `int&`. Then by [*reference collapsing*](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html), `T& &&` becomes `T&`.

Comment: "In the case of #1, the final function template parameter type would be `T`" - it is not clear what you mean here. Of course, the template parameter type is `T` - that what you called it in your code. Meanwhile, the deduced type will be `T == int &`. The function parameter type will be `int & &&`, which collapses to `int &`.

Comment: @BoBTFish Where can I find the relevant wording (about reference collapsing) in the standard?

Comment: @AnT Do you find "final" ambiguous? The reason I used the word is because `T&&` itself is not directly used for type deduction.

Comment: I got a headache just reading the title ;)

Comment: @Il-seobBae From a quick glance, [8.3.2 paragraph 6](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf#220). (The phrase "reference collapsing" is used elsewhere in The Standard, linking to this section).

Comment: @Il-seob Bae: No, `T` is the type we are trying to deduce. And it seems that you are saying that the final result of the deduction is `T`. Yes, but I don't understand the point you are trying to make by saying this. It is like saying that "Solution of equation `x+5=10` is `x`". Yes, we know that it is `x`, but what is the point of reiterating it?

Comment: @AnT If that's the case, sorry for my poor expression. I was talking about the final type of P (which actually participate in the type deduction), not final result of the deduction.